Pinscript 2 - Write strategy instructions for alerts and webhook
I have an indicator that is still written in Pinscript 2. I tried to convert the indicator to Pinescript 5.
Unfortunately, the indicator loses its precision when converted to Pinescript. The displays become much less precise and therefore almost unusable.
So I tried to leave the script in Pinescript and write an instruction for my webhook using  strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, comment= "Long TSLA") .
Unfortunately, I was unable to get the comment instruction to be transmitted via my webhook. Only the name of the indicator arrives and not the comment instruction for the trade execution. What am I doing wrong and is it even possible in Pinescript 2 or 3 to send a strategy.entry instruction in the code to an alert? Or would converting the code to Pinescript 3 help?
Here is the indicator:

//@version=2
strategy("Test 141 Vers 2 - GetTrendStrategy", overlay=true)
tim=input('28')
out1 = security(tickerid, tim, open)
out2 = security(tickerid, tim, close)
tickid = tickerid
plot(out1,color=red, linewidth = 3, transp = 0)
plot(out2,color=green, linewidth = 3, transp = 0)


long_com = "LL_Alert Long {{ticker}}"
short_com = "SS_Alert Short {{ticker}}"


// Long
longCondition = crossover(security(tickerid, tim, close),security(tickerid, tim, open))

if (longCondition)
    //strategy.entry("LL_Alert Long {tickerid}", strategy.long)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)  // , comment="Enter Long"

//alertcondition(longCondition, title='LL_Alert', message='LL_Alert Long {tickerid}')
alertcondition(longCondition, title="Long Entry Alert", message="Long Entry Triggered! Price: {{close}} Time: {{time}}")

plotshape(longCondition, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=green, transp = 0, size = size.normal)


// Short
shortCondition = crossunder(security(tickerid, tim, close),security(tickerid, tim, open))

if (shortCondition)
    //strategy.entry("SS_Alert Short {tickerid}", strategy.short)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

//alertcondition(shortCondition, title='SS_Alert', message='SS_Alert Short {tickerid}')
alertcondition(shortCondition, title="Short Entry Alert", message="Short Entry Triggered! Price: {{close}} Time: {{time}}")

plotshape(shortCondition, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=red, transp = 0, size = size.normal)




Why do you want to use comment? Why not simply alert()? It is just a string that you need to send.

I'm not aware any feature getting "worse" when switching from v2 to v5. Defaults might have changed, sure, but you should be able to achieve the same in v5 as in v2.
